# In SSRS, is it possible to have 2 values for one parameter? - pulling from SharePoint so I can't edit stored procedure to use 'in'

Tags: list, sharepoint, reporting-services

I have a SSRS report that pulls information from a SharePoint list.  All was well until the structure of the SharePoint list was changed.  To be more specific, we had a particular column set up to be a drop down list and now it has been changed to be a checkbox.  The SSRS report has a parameter based on this particular value, now being a checkbox.

Some of the values returned by the underlying query have **;#** before and after the text values, although not all of them.  We can run the SSRS report, selecting All as the parameter and everything is returned correctly.  However, if we select a specific name, than only the rows that are not formatted as being a checkbox are returned.

When editing the Report Parameters, is it possible to have 1 label, but 2 values?  e.g. "value" and ";#value;#

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that if I filter the data set, I can replace the value pulled from the database.  `Replace(valueFromDatabase, ";#", "")`.

It's the opposite of using 2 values for one parameter...